# Opensearch: Insert documents (Fast) with CBOR and Bulking

Tags: python, opensearch, cbor

I have to insert a lot of documents as fast as possible to an **Opensearch Server (2.1.0)** from a python client.
I am already using the Bulking API and considering using the CBOR format instead of plain JSON. Is CBOR with a significance faster than plain JSON because the size should be smaller and therefore a bit less to be parsed?

How can I check if Opensearch accepts CBOR? The elasticsearch Documentation is a bit more detailed, but I can not get the results the ElasticDoc states.

Also, is there anything I can do besides using the REST API to insert documents, maybe even simultaneously?

Comment: I'd be happy to get a response as well, formatting requests (with decimal numbers) in JSON is by itself a performance killer